# ListView vanishes after repaint

Tags: android, listview, repaint

I have the following code:

```
public void addToList(View view) {

    String str = edit.getText().toString();
    list.add(str);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    //new QueryInList().execute("hi");
   // Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);
    //startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    while (bsp <10)
    {
        list.add(bsp.toString());
        bsp++;
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    ListView v;
    v = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.v);
    edit  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textfield);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list );
    v.setAdapter(adapter);
    //v.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

The first method is my onClick method, it is evoked whenever I press a button.
Now, my idea was that in such a case the gui gets repainted.
This happens, however, the Listview then vanishes. Do I have to repaint it ? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android we use an `Adapter` to hold the data for a `ListView`. Whenever you make changes to the data set, the list then gets notified via an observer that the contents of the `Adapter` has changed. This however requires you to explicitly inform any observers about the change.

What you did is set the entire content view of your activity every time your click listener is invoked, instead what you should do is:

1.
Add the new item to your adapter:

```
adapter.add("Whatever");
```

2.
Notify any observers (in this case your `ListView`) about the change:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Make sure to keep a reference to your adapter as a class member.

Cheers.

Comment: Does that mean adding something to the adapter is the same as adding and item to the list which is displayed?

Comment: You can't really (or at least you should not) add views manually to a ListView. The Adapter is the one in charge of holding the data that should be displayed in the list, as well as generating and participating in the process of recycling the views to increase performance. So in general, yes, if you add an item to the adapter and notify about the change, that change should be reflected in your list. I would strongly recommend watching this old session: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70